# Kendo UI: navigate breaks when called from show for second time

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

In the **show** method of one of my views I run:

```
mobileApp.navigate('views/Login.html');
```

mobileApp is a kendo.mobile.Application-object.

This works fine the first time show runs. But the second time I get this exception:

"Cannot read property 'stop' of undefined"

The same happens if I put the navigate-code in beforeShow. But if I put it in another method triggered by a click on a button it works every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the [documentation and the code snippet](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/mobile/ui/view#events-beforeShow) for in the beforeShow event.